# Can flink use fixed number key to keyBy a datastream evenly to avoid data skew?

Tags: java, apache-flink, grafana, influxdb

i set keyby parallism 30，how can i find 30 unique keys to make datastream keyByed evenly?Does flink support this? cause i don't want too much key,and i will make the key a tag in influxdb,so i don't want to much key,avoiding oom in influxdb.But how could i use minimum key to keyby a datastream evenly?

i want to use flink to track every change (such as update/insert) on table in mysql.and i will count the change times for every table per seconds.but some table has too much changes to cause keyby data skew,so i want to use fixed number key to load balance the keyby stream.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it can, but from Your question I understand that You don't really need to use`keyBy()` and You just want to do this to rebalance the stream. In such case You can easily use the `rebalance()` on `DataStream` which will cause the stream to be partitioned using round robin algorithm, which will indeed cause the load to be distributed evenly.

Comment: cause i want to count table changes per second and sink the sum into influxdb,so my key for keyBy() in flink is (db_name+table_name+update/insert)，but some table has too much changes ,so it cause data skew when i do keyBy(). and i try rebalance before keyBy()，but it doesn't work. sir ,can u please give some advice?

Comment: or sir can you teach me how to keyBy() a dataStream with 30 unique String when the parallism is 30?if i have the unique key , i can keyBy the datastream with key(db_name+table_name+update/insert+unique_key)，i think the data skew problem will be overcome then